# JQuery parallel ajax rquest to express

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, jsonp

I'm using this code to send 10 ajax request to a server and get a response from Express:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://myserver.ca:3000/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
          data: { 
            reqType: "shpFrame", 
            startFrom: "",
            numOfReqSteps: "",
            callback : "callback"

          },
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonp: 'callback',
          jsonpCallback: 'testcb',
          cache: false,
        timeout: 50000,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);





        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);

        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that when send one ajax request I get response perfectly fine. But when I try to send more than one request at the same time(similar to above code) I get this error " error parsererror Error: testcb was not called". Again, when I have just one request at a time I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem but when I changed the name of the callback method dynamically on the server, it solved the problem